# detect the loss of precision in pure C++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Is it possible to detect the loss of precision, when you operate with floating-point numbers (of `float`, `double`, `long double` types)? Say:

```
template< typename F >
F const sum(F const & a, F const & b)
{
    F const sum_(a + b);
    // The loss of precision must be detected (here or one line above) if some fraction bit is lost due to rounding
    return sum_;
}
```

Especially intrested in case of when **x87** FPU is present on target architecture, but without the intervention of the `asm` routines into the pure C++ code. **C++11** or **gnu++11** specific features also accepted if any.

Comment: I think C++11 type traits for numerics do have something like that

Comment: maybe the `is_exact` value of the `numeric_limits<T>` type trait is what you're looking for

Comment: I think it is not possible statically, because of **P** bit in status word of **x87** FPU should be checked only after the binary operation action has been performed.

Comment: I see. i guess i do not know then :-)

Comment: Note, that the question is about the loss of precision during the floating-point operations with arity == 2.

Comment: check that `sum-a==b` and `sum-b==a`? Or try using fenv.h (not properly implemented by many compilers).

Comment: @MarcGlisse offers a good approach.  It will not catch **all** precision loss, but it will catch almost all.

Comment: About x87 in particular, I am sure you'll find plenty of good discussions on the web (or even on SO). It complicates things because of double rounding at unpredictable times. gcc has flags to deal with it (some of which only work for C). Most portable is to write sum to a volatile variable and read it back (forces rounding).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard is very vague on the concept of floating point precision.  There is no fully standard-conforming way to detect precision loss.

GNU [provides an extension](http://linux.die.net/man/3/feenableexcept) to enable floating-point exceptions.  The exception you would want to trap is `FE_INEXACT`.

Comment: It's not so much a GNU extension as GNU trying to be compliant with multiple standards. One is the language itself. Another is the IEC floating point standard, which is what dictates those floating point exceptions.

Comment: @DavidHammen good info.  Interestingly (unlike C99) the C++ standard also doesn't promise IEC floats.  It's a cloudy topic.

Comment: C99 advertises through `__STDC_IEC_559__` and C++98 through `std::numeric_limits<...>::is_iec559`.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider to use the [interval arithmetic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm) in boost library. It can guarantee the property that the error for an interval is always increasing during calculation: `∀ x ∈[a,b], f(x) ∈ f([a,b])`.

In your case, you might consider to use the initial range `[a-EPS,a+EPS]` for the initial number `a`. After a series of operations, the `abs(y-x)` for the resulting interval `[x,y]` will be the (maximum) loss of precision you want to know.

Comment: I havent really try that, but there should be a policy for you to always round it outward. It also mention the x87 floating-point unit, so I think it would be helpful for you

Comment: Boost handles the rounding for you. Note that you can start from [a,a], and detect loss of precision when the interval is not a point anymore (i.e. do the operation once rounded up, once rounded down, and compare).

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

template <typename F> F sum (const F a, const F b, F &error) {
    int round = fegetround();

    fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    F c = a + b;

    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    F c_lo = a + b;

    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    F c_hi = a + b;

    fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    error = std::max((c - c_lo), (c_hi - c));

    fesetround(round);

    return c;
}


int main() {
    float a = 23.23528;
    float b = 4.234;
    float e;

    std::cout << sum(a, b, e) << std::endl;
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

A quick estimate of the maximum error amount is returned in the `error` argument. Bear in mind that switching the rounding mode flushes the floating-point unit (FPU) pipeline, so don't expect blazing fast speeds.

A better solution would be to try Interval Arithmetic (tends to give pessimistic error intervals, because variable correlations are not accounted for), or Affine Arithmetic (tracks variable correlations, and thus gives somewhat tighter error bounds).

Read here for a primer in these methods:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.8089

Comment: It safer to save FPU control word using `fgetround` before first call of `fesetround` then restore it at the end.

Comment: It even better to use algebraic numbers, if you need true general precision.

Comment: Answer has been updated. Do you mean symbolic variables? Yes, they're great - if the problem permits their use.

Comment: I mean similar to http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_kernel_d/index.html implementations.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that will help you is `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon`, which returns "the difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable." In other words, it tells you the largest `x`>0 such that `1+x` evaluates to 1.